# Make a wpf child window and parent window synchronized? i.e Dragging, resizing etc?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have wpf child window overlayed on top of a parent wpf window. I want to synchronize both of them in terms of dragging , resizing etc.
In other words, If I drag the Parent window the child window should also move the same amount in real time. I also am planning not to let the child window go out of bounds of its parent window. Also , resizing the parent window should automatically adjust the child windows size proportionately and so on.
How would I go about setting up the framework for this?
As I am a relative beginner in this regard , any code samples will be really appreciated! Thanks to one and all!

Comment: Child windows already exhibit this behavior through the layout system. Do you mean owned window or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `LocationChanged` and `SizeChanged` events of the parent window in the dialogue window and use the information of the respective event arguments to manipulate your dialogue window.

I do not know exactly what information you get from those events but if this general idea does not help you i could look into it.